# How to change cell's color property when it is no longer active

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet event macro that fires when a hyperlink formula is clicked - it "highlights" (changes the cell interior color) the hyperlink destination cell so it is more visible to the end user. How do I change the destination cell to be "unhighlighted" (i.e. change the cell interior color back to white) when the user no longer needs it? i.e. i have turned the highligher "on", how do i turn it "off"? code below turns highlight "on":

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ControlPoint As String
Dim RowVar As Integer
Dim Destination As String

If InStr(1, Target.Cells(1, 1).Formula, "HYPERLINK") = 0 Then Exit Sub

ControlPoint = Target.Value

RowVar = Application.WorksheetFunction _
            .Match(ControlPoint, _
            Sheets("Control Point Log").Range("c1:c700"), 0)

Destination = "C" & RowVar

Sheets("Control Point Log").Range(Destination).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
        .TintAndShade = -9.99786370433668E-02
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You'd have to decide how you would know the user "no  longer needs" the highlighting.  That's the tricky part.  You *could* set an OnTime() call which resets the formatting after (say) 5 secs. Otherwise, it's hard to say what event should trigger an "unhighlight" of the cell.

Comment: That is a great idea, can you help me set that up?

Answer (score 0):

This all goes in the worksheet module for the sheet you want to capture events on. Note: you may need to modify the sheet codename from 'Sheet1' to whatever your sheet's codename is.

I simplified your highlighting a little to just change the fill color: I don't know what your "default" formatting should look like.

**EDIT**: now highlights on second sheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Const CLEAR_AFTER_SEC As Long = 4
Dim f As Range, trg As Range, addr As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set trg = Target.Cells(1)

    If InStr(1, trg.Formula, "HYPERLINK") = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") 'edit here for your sheet name
    Set f = sht.Range("C1:C700").Find(trg.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)

    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        addr = f.Address(False, False)
        Highlight addr

        f.Parent.Activate
        Application.Goto f

        Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, CLEAR_AFTER_SEC), _
                  "'Sheet1.Highlight """ & addr & """, True'"
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub Highlight(rng As String, Optional reverse As Boolean = False)
    'edit sheet name to suit...
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range(rng).Interior
        .Color = IIf(reverse, vbWhite, vbRed)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that tm and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I can't get this to work - like my code, it turns the highlight "on" but does not turn it off... I think because the location of the hyperlink and the location of the cell the hyperlink goes to are in different sheets - I did adjust for that, removing the Me.Range, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: this highlights but it still isn't turning it off after 4 seconds... i have added some code that turns it off [CODE]Public Sub Highlight(rng As String, Optional reverse As Boolean = False) With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Control Point Log").Range(rng).Interior .Color = IIf(reverse, vbWhite, vbRed) End With MsgBox "Click 'OK' below to unhighlight cell" With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Control Point Log").Range(rng).Interior .Color = IIf(reverse, vbRed, vbWhite) End With End Sub /[End CODE]

Comment: I don't know what the issue might be. Works for me (Win XP, Excel 2010)  As an end-user I'd find it a little disconcerting though: it's not "normal" for sheets to switch automatically on selecting a cell (unless purposefully clicking a hyperlink).  Why not just give the user a hyperlink which takes them to the desired cell?

Comment: I use Win XP Excel 2007; the end user clicks on a hyperlink that directs them to the desired cell in a different sheet, the sheets do not switch automatically on selecting any other cell (the hyperlink takes them to get more information about the object in the cell - kind of like how clicking on a wikipedia link takes you to more information about the object you clicked on).  The reason for highlight code as a worksheet event  was to make it easier for the user to see the desired cell in the new tab, a visual aid to direct the eyes to the cell since there are many items in that sheet.